# Using AddOnPageChangeListener to return page as Toast-Message

Tags: java, android

I am using ViewPager to swipe between fragments. 
Since `onPageSelectedListner()` method is deprecated, I have to use `AddOnPageChangeListener`

So my code looks like this:

```
 // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Question: My intent was to return the page  where the user is. Like, when you swipe from page 1 to 2, you get a Toast-Message that tells you ,you are at page 2. If you swipe forward, it tells you, you are at page 3 and so on.

But my methods in the OnClickListener are returning voids. How can I get the page position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :-

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You're on page " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

In this, `position` is the argument of the `onPageSelected` selected method. This position is set when the page is changed.

Comment: Hey, do you have Facebook or something like that to stay in touch concerning Android-Prgramming ? :)